# The Fields of Fractions Induced by Two Similar, but Distinct Integral Domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Consider the two rings $R_1=\{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]=a+b\sqrt{-3}\mid a, b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and $R_2=\{\frac{a+b\sqrt{-3}}{2}\mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z},a\,\,\textrm{and}\,\,b\,\,\textrm{both even or both odd}\}$.

Let $F_1$ and $F_2$ be the fields of fractions induced by $R_1$ and $R_2$ respectively. I want to describe the elements in these fields, and in particular determine whether they  are equal, or if one is contained in the other. **My suspicion at this point is that $F_1=F_2$, but the fields are throwing me for a loop**:

Here is my attempt at showing equality:

I'm pretty confident that $F_1=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-3}]$. If: $$\alpha = \frac{a+bi\sqrt{3}}{c+di\sqrt{3}} $$ is an arbitrary element of $F_1$, then by multiplying top and bottom by $(c-di\sqrt{3})$, we can express $\alpha$ in the form $p+qi\sqrt{3}$, where $p,q \in \mathbb{Q}$. Hence $F_1 \subseteq\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-3}]$. Conversely, any element of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-3}]$ can be written as the quotient of two elements of $R_1$, so $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-3}]\subseteq F_1$. We conclude that $F_1=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-3}]$.

Now, I would like to show that $F_2=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-3}]$. Inclusion in one direction is straightforward: any quotient of two elements in $R_2$ will take the form $(a+bi\sqrt{3})/(c+di\sqrt{3})$ and hence belong to $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-3}]$ by an argument similar to above. Now let $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-3}]$ be arbitrary. Then we may write $\beta$ in the form: $$\beta = \frac{v}{w}+\frac{x}{y}i\sqrt{3}, $$ with $v,w,x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $w\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$. Simple algebraic manipulation shows that: $$\beta = \frac{(2v)(2y)+(2x)(2w)i\sqrt{3}}{(2w)(2y)+0\cdot i \sqrt{3}}, $$ which shows that I have written $\beta$ as the quotient of two elements of $R_2$: namely, $\frac{1}{2}(4vy+4xwi\sqrt{3})$, and $\frac{1}{2}(4wy+0\cdot i \sqrt{3})$ -- note that the coefficients in each element are both even. So it appears that $\beta \in F_2$ and because $\beta\in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-3}]$ was arbitrary, we have that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-3}] \subseteq F_2$. Hence $F_2 = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-3}] = F_1$.

Is this legitimate? I feel a little bit strange about the previous paragraph (in particular, given that I haven't cancelled the 2's, but I suppose in the definition of $R_2$, it is not stipulated that $a/2$ and $b/2$ be written in reduced form).

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of specific verification, there is a simplier method to arrive $F_1=F_2$.

On the one hand,
$$\forall a,b\in\mathbb Z,a+b\sqrt{-3}=\frac{2a+2b\sqrt{-3}}{2}\Rightarrow R_1\subset R_2\Rightarrow F_1\subset F_2$$
and on the other hand,
$$\forall a,b\in\mathbb Z,\frac{a+b\sqrt{-3}}{2}\in F_1\Rightarrow R_2\subset F_1$$
Since $F_1$ is closed to those operations of field, $F_2\subset F_1$.